# ReactJS - how can I handle notifications to user based on server response?

Tags: reactjs

so I've been trying to figure out

**how to handle some notifications/alerts to show users some information based on what they typed in for example login form**.

```
const DoLogin = async (email, password) => {
  const loginTeacher = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/teachers/login",
    {
      email,
      password
    }
  );
  return loginTeacher;
};

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    logged: false,
    status: "",
    errorMessage: ""
  };

  onEmailChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onPassChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    DoLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("mysecrettoken", res.data.token);
        this.setState({ teacher: res.data, logged: true, status: res.status });
        alert("Successfully logged in");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert("Unable to login in, user not found");
      });
  };

  loginForm() {
    return (
      <div className="Login form">
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="email">
            Email:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.onEmailChange}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="password">
            Hasło:
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onPassChange}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
          <input type="button" value="Dodaj nauczyciela" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, whenever a user is able to login it shows alert with the message, but I don't think that's a good way to show user information.

Could you please help me with that? Some articles/libraries would be great. I've tried to implement `react toast` but I failed to do that.

Comment: Hey there! You just want to show notifications (alert, success message,warnings) based on the result of API, did you used any premade components like  "react toastify"?

Comment: Hey there @blackSheep I've tried to implement ``react toastify`` but I failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the details in the state (like you already do) and then access in the render method for conditional rendering if the user has logged in.

```
const DoLogin = async (email, password) => {
  const loginTeacher = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/teachers/login",
    {
      email,
      password
    }
  );
  return loginTeacher;
};

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    logged: false,
    status: "",
    errorMessage: ""
  };

  onEmailChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onPassChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    DoLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("mysecrettoken", res.data.token);
        this.setState({ teacher: res.data, logged: true, status: res.status, showingMessage: true });
        setTimeout(() => { 
           this.setState({ showingMessage: false })
        }, 2000)
        alert("Successfully logged in");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // update state with ERROR
        this.setState({ error: err.message })
        alert("Unable to login in, user not found");
      });
  };

  loginForm() {
    if (this.state.logged && this.state.showingMessage) {
      return (<div>You've logged in as {this.state.teacher.name}</div>)
    }
    return (
      <div className="Login form">
        {/* display ERROR */}
        {this.state.error && <span style="color:red">
          There was an error during registration: {this.state.error}.
        </span>}
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="email">
            Email:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.onEmailChange}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="password">
            Hasło:
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onPassChange}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" />
          <input type="button" value="Dodaj nauczyciela" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know where your render method is, but basically just access the state. You can also set a timeout after you received the data, and add another property on the state, like `showingMessage` which will be true at first, and then in say 2s will be false, then your condition would be `if (this.state.logged & this.state.showingMessage)`.

Comment: I have not pasted my render method because it's just render calling loginForm. Thanks for your response, but I have one more question. Let's say I have another form, where user types some emails, and then from server you get an error which says that this email is already in use and you have to use another one. How to catch error message/types from server ? I've tried different ways, but for now it only show red endpoint with some error code, but I want some details ( I send them from server, I don't know how to grab them )

Comment: yeah same logic applies see my updated answer: just set the state if case of error, and refer to it in the logicForm method. It's all about using the state together with conditional rendering. You can use shorted syntax like `{ this.state.error && <element /> }` in JSX. then when form is updated, you can clear the error. to do this, set up an onChange listener on each input I think...

Comment: All right, I'll give that a shot. Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: np checkout an example here https://github.com/dpck/form#form (ExampleForm) it's a separate package you don't need to use it (it's great you're implementing your own), but it's using conditionals for rendering. The SubmitForm basically stores { error, success } in the state, and then they are displayed below the form. good luck